# Rails: how to find all users older then n minutes ago where n is stored in joined group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, rspec, scope

I have `User` model and `Group` model. `User` belongs_to `Group`. `Group` has an attribute `check_minutes`.

I want to create two scopes in User model: `old` and `fresh`. Old users is users with `created_at` older than `user.group.check_minutes.ago`. And fresh users is users with `created_at` newer than `user.group.check_minutes.ago`.

I wrote the scopes:

```
  scope :old,   joins(:group).where("`users`.`created_at` <=
        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)")
  scope :fresh, joins(:group).where("`users`.`created_at` >
        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)")
```

And specs:

```
  describe "scopes" do
    let(:group) {Group.make :check_minutes => 20}
    let(:old_user) {User.make :group => group, :created_at => 30.minutes.ago}
    let(:new_user) {User.make :group => group, :created_at => 10.minutes.ago}

    context "#fresh" do
      it "should scope all new users" do
        User.fresh.should eq([ new_user ])
      end
    end
    context "#old" do
      it "should scope all old users" do
        User.old.should eq([ old_user ])
      end
    end
  end
```

Specs fails on `fresh` (for `old` it is ok):

```
  expected  [#<User id: 7967, ... >]
        got []
```

What's wrong?! How to force my scopes\specs to work well?

It would be great If you know the better way to organize scopes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scopes are OK.

The problem you're having is that Rails stores UTC time values in the database, regardlessly of the database's configured time zone, and converts them into your (Rails) timezone while doing ORM.

...Which means your scopes are *almost* OK - you just have to inject the 'Rails' current time into the query.

```
scope :old, lambda {  joins(:group).where(["`users`.`created_at` <=
    DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)", Time.zone.now]) }
scope :fresh, lambda { joins(:group).where(["`users`.`created_at` >
    DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL `groups`.`check_minutes` MINUTE)", Time.zone.now]) }
```

Comment: Sorry to be linking a Russian article on SO, but I have covered this in my blog: http://leonid.shevtsov.me/ru/time-now-vs-time-zone-now-in-rails